# Need help Shifting a 2D String array to the left

Tags: java, encryption, multidimensional-array

So far I've gotten as far as displaying a 26X26 array that looks like this:
abcd...
abcd...
abcd...

but I need it to do this:

abcd
bcda
cdab...

Basically each row is shifting one to the left, but every time I try something I get some error. Any help would be appreciated.

here's my code:

```
public static String [][] table(String [][] cipher){

    String [][] table = {{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}};

    for (int i =0; i < cipher.length; i++){

      cipher[i]  =  table[0];

      for(int j = 0; j< cipher[i].length; j++){

      cipher[j] = table[0];
  }
}
 return cipher;
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how to use **`substring()`** *(←hint)* on `"abcdef"` to produce `"abcd"` and `"ef"`, so you can concatenate them in opposite order to get `"efabcd"`?

Comment: Yes. I've tried the substring() method but i get a: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method substring(int)
  location: class java.lang.String[]

Comment: You can't use `substring` on `table[x]` or `cipher[x]` because `table` and `cipher` are `String[][]` and `table[x]` and `cipher[x]` are thus `String[]`.  You'd have to do `table[x][y]` or `cipher[x][y]` to obtain a `String`.  I think part of the problem is that you're unnecessarily using `String[][]`s where just `String[]` would do.

Comment: Why is `table` a 2D array of size 1x1? Why not just `String table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`

Comment: Is `cipher` supposed to be a 2D array of 1-character strings? E.g. `{ { "a", "b", "c" }, { "b", "c", "a" }, { "c", "a", "b" } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve with 2d arrays. But you can use a method like this to shift the `String` inside your array to the left.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        table(new String[26][26]);
    }

    public static String[][] table(String[][] cipher) {

        String[][] table = {{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}};
        for (int i = 0; i < cipher.length; i++) {
            String[] word = table[0];
            cipher[i] = leftShift(word, i);
        }
        return cipher;
    }

    public static String[] leftShift(String[] array, int number) {
        String word = array[0];
        number = number % word.length();
        return new String[]{word.substring(number) + word.substring(0, number)};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah, I need to map the table later on so I figured if I did a 2d array it would be easier to navigate. This worked. I'm less than a year old in java so yeah.. still a noob :p.

Comment: What is the point of using a 2D array, if the inner array is always just length 1? Might as well just create a 1D array. And if the result should have inner array of length 1, was is it pre-created with inner arrays of length 26?